# How to use MY SQL IN operator with where clause in laravel 5.4?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Can any one help me with that issue please.

I need to use MY-SQL (IN) operator within where clause in laravel 5.4, I have columns variable which is a variable length array holding columns names called "$cols" so I can not use "whereIn" cause I don't know the count of my conditions colomns here's my code

```
    conditions = [];
    if(!is_null($cols)){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($cols); $i++){
            $vals = explode("-", $values[$i]);
            $conditions[] = [$cols[$i], 'IN', $values[$i]];
        }
    }
    $data = DB::table('my_table')->where($conditions)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

so any one can help me how to do something like that

Thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$queryBuilder = DB::table('my_table');

if( ! empty($cols)){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($cols); $i++) {
      $vals = explode("-", $values[$i]);
      // adding whereIn() per column
      $queryBuilder->whereIn($cols[$i], $vals);
    }
}

$data = $queryBuilder
          ->orderBy('id','desc')
          ->get();
```

Comment: Nice, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries), you can use `whereIn`, e.g.:

```
$data = DB::table('my_table')
      ->where($conditions)
      ->whereIn('something', [val1, val2, val3])
      ->orderBy('id','desc')
      ->get();
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know how many columns should I use in my conditions so I can't use whereIn